# php two objects of the same database class. destruct failed to close database connection on second object

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if the title of this question does not explain the actual question. I couldn't find appropriate word to name the title of this question.

I have a database class like so:

```
class Database
{
  private $link;
  private $host, $username, $password, $database;

  public function __construct($setup)
  {
    if ($setup == 'default') {
        $this->host        = 'localhost';
        $this->username    = 'root';
        $this->password    = 'root';
        $this->database    = 'infobox_sierraleone';
    }

    if ($setup == 'promo') {
        $this->host        = 'localhost';
        $this->username    = 'root';
        $this->password    = 'root';
        $this->database    = 'infobox';
    }

    $this->link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password)
        OR die("There was a problem connecting to the database.");

    mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->link)
        OR die("There was a problem selecting the database.");

  }

  public function __destruct() 
  {
        mysql_close($this->link)
            OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");
  }

}
```

I have created to different objects of the class above in a separate file:

```
include 'conn/database.php';

$db = new Database('default');
$db_promo = new Database('promo');
```

When i run the above script, i get this message:

```
There was a problem disconnecting from the database.
```

I realise that this message if from the __destruct() function. 
I have researched for some time and i am still not clear why this message is showing and how to get rid of it.

Any sort of help will be much appreciated.

Thank You.

Edit:
removed the return statement that was in the constructor.

Comment: maybe php already closed it before __destruct is called.

Comment: Why does your constructor return `true`? Why does your constructor return anything at all?

Comment: thats a good question @GolezTrol. And i have no answer to that. I have not noticed it. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not destroying your own objects, they get destroyed by PHP when the script is finished. PHP then just destroys anything it's got, but not necessarily in the right order.

In this case, apparently PHP kills the MySQL connection first and then continues destroying other  objects, including yours. Your object then tries to disconnect the already disconnected database connection, which would go unnoticed, if you wouldn't let the script `die` on failure.

Comment: thanks @GolezTrol. I just tried to run a query right after the two objects have been declared, using the first object (first database instance). And i get feedback such as "Table Does not exist". 

Looks like the query is running with the second object's credential.